# How to get process that aren't of windows system?

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to get the processes that are not of windows system by powershell but I don't know how to do that.

For example, in my computer i have this programs that aren't of windows system [image_process (click here to see)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbMvM.jpg)

I wrote this code  but it doesn't work correctly.

```
$gp = Get-Process | Where-OBject {$_.CPU -ne $null}
    if($global:pwshv -ge 7)
        {$gp = $gp | Where-Object -Property SI -ne 0}

$gp
```

In the "powershell ise" return this [my_code_return_this (click here to see)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFIQP.jpg) (in the image more processes are missing, but they are below)

And i only want to get the processes that are in the first image.

I need a command by powershell that returns the processes (programs running) that are not from windows.

Comment: `processes that are in the first image` Those are not processes, they are what Task Manager calls applications. The actual processes are under the Details tab.

Comment: yes, but that is what processes I want to get through the powershell. I need a command by powershell that returns the processes (programs actually) that are not from windows. To do certain things with them.

Comment: Not sure what "*programs that are not from windows*" is supposed to mean, but maybe [get the list of open applications on windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/121874/get-the-list-of-open-applications-on-windows) is what you are looking for.

Comment: [returns the processes (programs actually) that are not from windows]   ---   Are you saying you want to see all running programs/processes that are not Microsoft products or services? Anything running on Windows is, of course, Windows programs/processes, since they all call Windows proper to run..

Comment: dxiv, thanks my friend, that anwser was useful for me.